# Get windows details like product key, domain name, user name, etc.

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How can I get Operating system details like OS `Serial Number`(OS Product key), `User Domain Name`,`User Name` and `PC Full Name`?
What is the best way and optimal way to get it?

Comment: What is the version of Windows you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742389/get-pc-system-information-on-windows-machine-c-sharp-script

Comment: Which "serial number" are you trying to get? Windows, motherboard, etc?

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that your name is an anagram of a codeplex project for extracting a product key from windows - http://wpkf.codeplex.com/ ? Regardless, as I've mentioned in my updated answer, it may be able to help you, especially being .NET and open source.

Comment: It is Just a coincidence :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### System.Environment

Check out the (static) [`System.Environment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) class.

It has properties for [`MachineName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename.aspx), [`UserDomainName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx), and [`UserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx).

### System.Management

If you're looking for the BIOS serial number (or lots of info on other hardware) you might try the [`System.Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace, specifically [`SelectQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.selectquery.aspx) and [`ManagementObjectSearcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.aspx).

```
var query = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Bios");
var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
foreach (ManagementBaseObject item in search.Get())
{
    string serial = item["SerialNumber"] as string;
    if (serial != null)
        return serial;
}
```

You can get other info about the machine by querying, for example, on `Win32_Processor` or others as listed on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389273.aspx). This is using [`WMI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582.aspx) via [`WQL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WQL).

### Windows product key via registry

For an OS serial number, in many versions of Windows, it is stored in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId`, however it is in some encoded form and needs to be decoded to get the product key.

You can use the following method to decode this value, found [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/willemf/archive/2006/04/23/76125.aspx) (but slightly modified for clarity).

```
public string DecodeProductKey(byte[] digitalProductId)
{
    // Possible alpha-numeric characters in product key.
    const string digits = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789";
    // Length of decoded product key in byte-form. Each byte represents 2 chars.
    const int decodeStringLength = 15;
    // Decoded product key is of length 29
    char[] decodedChars = new char[29];

    // Extract encoded product key from bytes [52,67]
    List<byte> hexPid = new List<byte>();
    for (int i = 52; i <= 67; i++)
    {
        hexPid.Add(digitalProductId[i]);
    }

    // Decode characters
    for (int i = decodedChars.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // Every sixth char is a separator.
        if ((i + 1) % 6 == 0)
        {
            decodedChars[i] = '-';
        }
        else
        {
            // Do the actual decoding.
            int digitMapIndex = 0;
            for (int j = decodeStringLength - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                int byteValue = (digitMapIndex << 8) | (byte)hexPid[j];
                hexPid[j] = (byte)(byteValue / 24);
                digitMapIndex = byteValue % 24;
                decodedChars[i] = digits[digitMapIndex];
            }
        }
    }

    return new string(decodedChars);
}
```

Alternatively, I found an open source c# project that supposedly can extract the product key for any version of windows: http://wpkf.codeplex.com/ It uses the method given above and provides some additional information about the machine.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getipglobalproperties.aspx)
To get network related information:

```
var conInfo = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
Console.WriteLine(conInfo.HostName);
Console.WriteLine(conInfo.DomainName);
...
```

For Machine Name use [Environment.MachineName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.MachineName);
```

Comment: Nope, this method cant even get the IP address, and the OP is asking for the Windows Key.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try the [Systeminformation class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.aspx) it provides alot of information about the current system environment, take a look at the example on MSDN site. It has the followign properties:

[ComputerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.computername.aspx), [UserDomianName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.userdomainname.aspx), [UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.username.aspx) ...etc

Comment: Note that this depends on WinForms.

Comment: SystemInformation Class, only useful information is those 3 you said (ComputerName, UserDomianName, UserName) and Screen Resolution, NOTHING ELSE, Windows Product key from this? Not even close to it.