# How to Get Product Keys (e.g. Adobe, Office) in Windows?

Tags: c#, registry, product-key

There are several answered questions about how to get the Windows OS Product Key like [Get windows details like product key, domain name, user name, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854322/get-windows-details-like-product-key-domain-name-user-name-etc), but I was wondering how to programmatically get the Product Key for a piece of installed software. [Uninstall Registry Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is really nice as it has a lot of attributes tied to an installed program, but none of the attributes involve a Product Key so I was wondering if there's some other means via some C# library or some such to get the Product Key for an arbitrary piece of software and how to get it via C#.

Comment: Why do you want to get product key? Most uses of that seem rather nefarious.

Comment: I'm planning on developing an open source application that outputs a csv with a list of installed programs and product keys in the case a persons Windows migration to Windows 10 goes bad and they want something to easily defer to install the programs they previously had (I myself personally keep such a list in the cloud sorted by priority of installation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no standard way that every program stores it's product key or licensing. For example, you can recover the Office product key from 2010 and prior, but with 2013, I do not believe it's possible. Many products have the activation details either encrypted in the registry or using a cloud-based solution (Office 365, Adobe CC). You can try to research the individual products you would like to target to get a better sense of how each program is handled.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the different registry hives and search them recursive for "keywords" like:

```
  var reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software");
    SearchRecursive(reg);
    ...
    private void SearchRecursive(ReigstryKey reg)
    {
       var subkeys = reg.GetSubKeyNames();
       var values = reg.GetValueNames();
       foreach (var value in values)
       {
          ...
       }
    }
```

- Serial
- ProductID
- DigitalProductId
  ....

I think You'll need some kind of filter at the end, there might be a lot of "wrong hits".