# How do I get client computer details (RAM, processor, HDD) in ASP.NET server?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Is there any way to get client computer hardware configuration from into an ASP.NET server? The information I'm seeking is:

- Total RAM
- Processor details
- HDD

Comment: You tagged this as ASP.NET. Are you interested in getting the details of the server, or the client? "Local" isn't clear in this context.

Comment: Client computer(users pc...)

Comment: Some of that information is available on the client side with JavaScript, and then you can communicate that back to the server. So really, your question has nothing to do with ASP.NET or C#. The rest of the information you have to run some executable code on the client's machine to retrieve, and report that back to your site.

Comment: [Here ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742389/get-pc-system-information-on-windows-machine-c-sharp-script)has the same question. Check it.

Comment: @Roshan No, that's completely irrelevant. This is a web context, getting details about the client onto the server.

Comment: For the client you can only get what is in Request.ServerVariables, if you need more info, you need to get the user to download and run an exe to gather this and report back. Oh, and what is in Request.Browser. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx for other possibilities.

Comment: @mason im sorry ..

Comment: Only windows form is the way ?

Comment: @NAJEEB No, *any* executable that's not sandboxed that you can run on the client's computer can get that information. It doesn't have to be Windows Forms. It could be WPF, UWP, console, Java, Python etc.

Comment: @Roshan Now that you know your comment is irrelevant, it'd be best to delete it.